# Illegible fonts in one part of a wine application

Tags: linux, fonts, wine

I'm having a weird wine font problem when trying to run the Portable D&D 4e Compendium on linux.

Here's an image of the issue: [image]

As you can see (it might be easier to see if you open it fully instead of looking at it in preview size), the fonts in the left half of the program are fine and readable, but the fonts in the right half of the program are blocky and horizontally smeared, making them borderline unreadable.

I tried installing winetricks corefonts, but that didn't solve the issue. I also tried FREETYPE_PROPERTIES="truetype:interpreter-version=35" since I saw it suggested online and that didn't help either. Any suggestions?

Comment: When looking at it in Windows, is the font in the detail window different from the other fonts?

Comment: I don't have Windows on hand right now to check. I could ask a friend to install the compendium soon, though. But I do think off my memory that the fonts were different.

Comment: We need to find out what the font should be via Windows and then see if that font is available via your Package Manager. Note that if the font isn't available, we'll need to find a member of it's family for a default fall back

Comment: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1142619010647740546/1195007863999971450/image.png @eyoung100

Comment: I tried the nuclear option and installed winetricks allfonts, this did not solve the problem.

Comment: Does Resizing the Window help or hurt the problem?

Comment: No effect from that. @eyoung100

Comment: Would [4e Compendium Downloader](https://github.com/Sheep-y/trpg-dnd-4e-db) be a suitable replacement?  I believe this may be a frames bug in the code.

Comment: Forgot to add, I'm not recommending this per se.  he object here is to find a native linux application, and drop using this in WINE

Comment: @eyoung100 it is not a suitable replacement because of feature disparity. The extra features are why I want to get this offline compendium to work.

Comment: Did you try installing all the fonts from windows? (You copy the fonts directory from a windows installation to /usr/local/share/fonts/dirnameofyourchoice; then run fc-cache --force); it's also possible you may need to tweak your fontconfig rules to fix this.

Comment: If this is a Frame bug as I suspect, there are some ie* fixes in winetricks  its been awhile though, so I cant remember what they are.  As the frame renders it DOESN'T REFRESH on scroll.

Comment: @eyoung100 I tried installing first ie8 and then ie7 via winetricks and neither did anything to help. Is that what you meant or was there something else?

Comment: That is what I meant.

Comment: @Mash please share references or links where we can find the application you are talking about

Comment: @mattia.b89 as far as I know this is an abandonware application that new users cannot legally obtain anymore.

Comment: ok, the only thing I can add is: UI looks like JAVA, you should address your search in that direction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [a solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1564533/blurred-font-color-wine).

regedit `HKCU/Control Panel/Desktop` and set the following values:

```
FontSmoothing=2
FontSmoothingOrientation=00000001
FontSmoothingType=00000002
FFontSmoothingGamma=00000578
```

This completely fixed all graphical issues. It somehow even fixed seemingly non-font-related issues like everything becoming smeared upon scrolling around in the detail panel.